# Which setting changes the background color of Jupyter cells in Pycharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

The brownish color they have in my theme is low-contrast. How do I change it?

[image: pycharm jupyter cell color]

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be "Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Notebooks -> Code cell background"

[image]